# DialogFragment - make it as a member of the outerclass instead of static inner class

Tags: android, inner-classes, android-dialogfragment, outer-classes

this is a small example from Android tutorial showing a DialogFragment and DatePicker.
Its implemented as a static inner class of the MainActivity. I wonder if its possible to change the code so that it becomes a member-function of MainActivity instead?

EDIT: the thing is that I want to set a textview in the MainActivity from this inner class where the DialogFragment is residing. But this inner class is static -in fact HAS to be static. ANd since its static, the callback that is made to main Activity - the callback function - also has to be static. But if this function is static - how can I access the textview in the MainActivity?

thanks!

```
TextView tv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);

 }


 public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
      newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
      newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); 
 }

 public static void notifyActivity() {
    // want to change the textview here but cannot since the method is static.
 }



 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private int year, month, day;

    @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog date = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), DatePickerFragment.this, year, month, day);
        date.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        notifyActivity(); 
                    }
                });
        return date;

    }
```

Comment: "I wonder if its possible to change the code so that it becomes a member-function of MainActivity instead?" -- what code? The whole `Fragment`?

Comment: It implements a callback interface, so it seems unlikely. Otherwise you'd be able to do it using an anonymous subclass of DialogFragment (although not sure why you would want to do that either).

Comment: @Zhuinden the problem is that I want to set a textview in the MainActivity from a callback from this class (not shown here). But since the callback-funcktion residing in MainActivity also has to be static - i cannot set the textview in the MainActivity

Comment: ...the callback function static? What? You're going to need to post more code, because I'm not sure what you mean, but it sure sounds wrong.

Comment: Describe exactly what you want to happen and not how you think it should happen.

Comment: @beplaya - update made

Comment: @user3155478 Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html